# Unable satisfy constraints when changing multiplier in constraintWithItem

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, constraints, containers

I'm  trying to get my container view working. The problem is when changing the multiplier to something diffrent than 0.5 I get :

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

for example, If I change *c2 multipier to 0.4 and *c8 to 0.6 I get the above error. But if I change back to 0.5 it´s all fine. What am I doing wrong here? 
I got some more constraints but they are for vertically layout so I don´t think they are the problem.

```
 NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentView
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0];


NSLayoutConstraint *c2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentView
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:.4
                                                       constant:0.0];


// detailView

NSLayoutConstraint *c7 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: detailView
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0];


NSLayoutConstraint *c8 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: detailView
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:.6
                                                       constant:0.0];
```

Comment: could you add the code where you create the `detailView` and `contentView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success using relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual.

For eg :

```
        [self.view addConstraint:

             [

              NSLayoutConstraint

              constraintWithItem: _accountRegisteredDateLabel
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
              toItem:self.view
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
              multiplier:.30
              constant:0


              ]

         ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I would answer my own question. 
I ended up setting one views multiplier to 0.609375 and the other one to 0.390625
That worked great for me!

Why it failed with 0.4 and 0.6 was because it didn't add up with the total space.
My two views were going to be next to each other with a total space of 1024px(ipad).

0.4 * 1024 = 409,6

0.6 * 1024 = 614,4

My understanding is that somehow the constraintWithItem method not care about the remainders and throw an error.

So just come up with a number that doesn't give you any remainders

0.390625 * 1024 = 400

0.609375 * 1024 = 624